# Why plot_model in Keras does not plot the model correctly?

Tags: tensorflow, plot, keras, neural-network, visualization

I want to visualize my neural net. Therefore, I use `from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model` and use it like this:

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(8, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    plot_model(model, to_file="model.png", show_shapes=True)
```

But, when I open the graphic, it looks like this:

[image]

What is wrong with my code? I do not see any error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is that the model has not been built because it does not know its input shape. Either specify the input shape of the model on the first layer using `input_shape` (or `input_dim`) argument, or alternatively start fitting the model on some data by calling `fit` method (so the input shape could be automatically inferred). Also, as mentioned by @xdurch0 in the comments section, another option is to call `build` method of the model and pass it the input shape as argument.

Comment: Keras models also have a `build` method which allows to specify an input shape.

Comment: Cool, thanks. However, only input_dim or input_shape was required. It also does not matter whether you put the plot_model before or after model.fit(...). As long as you do not specify input_dim/shape the plot looks always like the one above, no matter where you have put it in your code.

Comment: @toom Unfortunately, `tf.keras` has messed up some little things and it has weird/different behavior compared to native keras. If instead of using `tf.keras` you use the `keras` itself, you would realize using either of `build` or `fit` method would build the model and then if call `plot_model` it would work correctly. (Note: I am not recommending to use `keras` over `tf.keras`. I am just informing you of the different/inconsistent behavior of `tf.keras`).

Comment: I see. I am not so familiar with deep learning frameworks, so I though starting with Tensorflow might be a good idea. To me the difference between Keras and TF is not so clear yet... But I will find out :)